# GinMapProvider Stack Overflow

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I am getting a stack overflow but I think I have nailed down the problem. The issue is a recursive inject when binding my panel widget. The problem I have ran into is that my PanelWidget takes the Map as a parameter. The problem is then that that this creates an infinite loop.

**GinMapProvider**

```
    GinMapBinder<String, IDashboardWidget> mapBinder = GinMapBinder
            .newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, IDashboardWidget.class);

    mapBinder.addBinding(IGaugeWidgetModel.class.getName()).to(MockGaugeWidget.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding(IPlotWidgetModel.class.getName()).to(PlotWidget.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding(ITableWidgetModel.class.getName()).to(TableWidget.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding(IPanelWidgetModel.class.getName()).to(PanelWidget.class);
```

If I remove `Map<String, IDashboardWidget>` the problem goes away of course.

**PanelWidget class**

```
@Inject
public PanelWidget(final EventBus eventBus, final Resources resources, Map<String, IDashboardWidget> widgetProvider) {
    super(eventBus, resources);
    this.widgetProvider = widgetProvider;
    initWidget(GWT.<Binder> create(Binder.class).createAndBindUi(this));
    widgetsPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE);

    this.addDomHandler(widgetSelectedHandler, ClickEvent.getType());
}
```

I tried this also and inject the WidgetFactory class but this did not solve my problem either. I had hoped creating a singleton would stop it from recreating the bindings.

```
@Inject
@Provides
@Singleton
WidgetFactory widgetFactory(Map<String, IDashboardWidget> widgetProvider) {
    return new WidgetFactory(widgetProvider);
}
```

BTW I am running this in a GWTTestCase but I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: Is one of your map values depending on `PanelWidget` maybe? It looks to me like you should maybe rather inject a `Map<String, Provider<IDashboardWidget>>`

Comment: THOMAS!! you rock. Changing the @Inject constructor parameter to Provider<IDashboardWidget> solved the problem. Add an answer and Ill send the points.

Comment: Done, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have circular dependencies, specifically between one of the things you put in the map and the `PanelWidget`.

Given the look of your code (`WidgetFactory`), I think you might actually need a `Map<String, Provider<IDashboardWidget>>` instead of a `Map<String, IDashboardWidget>`. And that would cut the circular dependency as a side effect.